# go channel capacity ,why does it take one more elements than I specified

Tags: go, channel

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
     message := make(chan string ,1) // no buffer
     count := 3

     go func() {
          for i := 1; i <= count; i++ {
               fmt.Println("send message")
               message <- fmt.Sprintf("message %d", i)
          }
     }()

     time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)

     for i := 1; i <= count; i++ {
          fmt.Println(<-message)
     }
}
```

The output is

```
send message
send message  [wait for 3 sec]
message 1
send message
message 2
message 3
```

If I change `message := make(chan string ,1) // no buffer` to

```
message := make(chan string ,2) // no buffer
```

I got

```
send message
send message
send message [wait 3 sec]
message 1
message 2
message 3
```

Why 2 buffers channel can store 3 string objects? not 2?

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works like this because the buffer holds N messages before it blocks. When the N+1 messages comes in GO will see that it exceeds the capacity you specified and will have to block, waiting for something to take from that channel. When passing a buffer size the sender will always block on N+1 message.

So for instance with size 2 you have an empty buffer:

[][]

Then a message comes in, is put in the buffer:

[m1][]

Then another one, we can keep on going because we have space in the buffer

[m1][m2]

Then another comes in, ups we don't have more space in the buffer so we block

[m1][m2]m3 -> block

Something like this.

The size is basically the number of messages that can be sent to the buffer without blocking.

For the future I recommend http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels

```
var sem = make(chan int, MaxOutstanding)
```

> Once MaxOutstanding handlers are executing process, any more will
>   block trying to send into the filled channel buffer, until one of the
>   existing handlers finishes and receives from the buffer.